# Open terminal from html using href ssh:// url with command line options

Tags: javascript, html, url, ssh, terminal

I'd like to create a url link that launches terminal (from webpage or browser such as chrome or safari) and ssh's to a box and launches remote commands (for example `ls`), in terminal it would look like:
`ssh user@1.2.3.4 'ls'`

I've tried:

`<a href='ssh://user@1.2.3.4 "ls"'>SSH with ls</a>`

but this does nothing.
and this works (without any commands):

`<a href='ssh://user@1.2.3.4'>SSH</a>`

Is this possible in HTML? I'll also accept answers that use Javascript.

Comment: You would need to have the user set what program the browser instructs to handle SSH links

Comment: thats fine, assuming they are using `Terminal.app` on Mac os

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. If you search for "ssh url handler" and maybe add the target browser & platform, you'll find various pages discussing how to set this up.

Comment: @Kenster no luck with that search

Comment: This is not possible using `Terminal.app`. It is still possible with `iTerm` if that works for you and not without a specific profile in iTerm. So by default you can't make it work across system without some configuration

Comment: This is dangerous.

Comment: Having a command included in the URL looks dangerous and could be a security risk. Usually that part of the URL is reserved for directory names. Look at how [**`scp`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) handles SSH URLs. [For example](https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye), `scp -r dvader@deathstar.com:~/revenge ~/revenge`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have looked at multiple sources and tried different combinations and come to below understanding

- There was no standard defined for the SSH URI to specify commands. So it is up to the process taking the input to understand how to use it
- By default `Terminal.app` handles the SSH url and there is no documentation that it supports command
- The app receiving the URL, doesn't get the URL as an argument, it needs to fetch it using some event. You can refer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46666/how-to-access-a-clicked-url-in-a-url-handler-application-created-in-automator) for the same
- You can configure iTerm to handle SSH handler and access the URL that was passed as describe [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-discuss/r0Rk_WZaGWk)
- You can create a custom app that handles the URL and does support commands and other things you want

**Doing it using iTerm**

You create a new profile and enable SSH URL handler in the same

[image: SSH handling]

So used below sample page

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="ssh://vagrant@vm/ls -alh">ls -alh</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And below command in my `iTerm` SSH profile

```
/usr/bin/ssh $$USER$$@$$HOST$$  $(echo $$PATH$$ | tr -d '/')
```

And the result was

[image: Result]

Of course you want to run a python script or something and pass it these values and let it do such things for additional functionalities. But this shows how you could achieve such a setup

**Key References**

[url scheme for ssh: Calling command on remote host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542732/url-scheme-for-ssh-calling-command-on-remote-host)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75668/why-doesnt-the-ssh-command-follow-rfc-on-uri

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-discuss/r0Rk_WZaGWk

http://www.rubicode.com/Software/Bundles.html#RCDefaultApp

https://superuser.com/questions/379342/setting-iterm2-as-the-default-terminal-osx-lion

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46666/how-to-access-a-clicked-url-in-a-url-handler-application-created-in-automator

https://support.shotgunsoftware.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/209485898-Launching-External-Applications-using-Custom-Protocols-under-OSX

Comment: Having a command included in the URL looks dangerous and could be a security risk. Usually that part of the URL is reserved for directory names. Look at how [**`scp`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) handles SSH URLs. [For example](https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye), `scp -r dvader@deathstar.com:~/revenge ~/revenge`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if this will help, but have you considered using a proxy / bridge to connect to server using SSH? For example: https://github.com/novnc/websockify

> Websockify is a WebSocket to TCP proxy/bridge. This allows a browser
>   to connect to any application/server/service.

This way instead of relying on SSH Client, you can directly communicate with server from your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users on Big Sur 11.6 you can in fact do this with Apple apps.  A simple test will show.

1. Open up Notes.app or TextEdit.app and create some text.
2. Select a word or sentence and hit Edit → Attach link (⌘K)
3. Create the url as `ssh://user@host` or `ssh://host` in the dialog.

Viola!